# How to draw a heptagon using Python Turtle with the point at the top?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am drawing a heptagon using this code:

```py
tegan.setheading(0);

for i in range (7):
    tegan.right(51.43)
    tegan.forward(100)
```

However, this code always draws the shape with a flat edge at the top and I want the point at the top. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe change `right()` to `left()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make an heptagon, you need to rotate 360°/7 each step. To have the point up, you rotate only half on the first step.

One trick to do this is to rotate in one direction (here left) half the angle, and then proceed in the other direction with the full angle seven times. Another possibility is to write a condition in the loop for the first step, or split the code in two.

```
import turtle
angle = 360/7
turtle.left(angle/2)
for i in range(7): 
    turtle.right(angle)
    turtle.forward(100)
```

[image]

Comment: oh goodness yes, I see now I was looking at the inner angle thinking they are all equal when I should have been concerned with the angle relative to the initial turtle heading of zero. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can simply do:

```
import turtle

turtle.circle(-116, steps=7)

turtle.done()
```

[image]